# Adding fixed text over cardscrollview

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I was wondering if anyone knows...if I have a cardscrollview in my app, is there a way to display some sort of anchored text or anything of the sort at the top of the cards?

Like say for example the user is scrolling through some images, I want to say "Choose an image" at the top. It looks weird if I add the text "Choose an image" to each and every card.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by creating a `FrameLayout` that has the `CardScrollView` added to it as one "layer", and then a `TextView` with your message on top of it, with layout gravity and margins configured to have it appear anchored to the bottom of the screen.